# I'm having IIS 8 to SQL Server 2012 conection issues

Tags: connection-string, sql-server-2012, iis-express, iis-8

Sorry in advance... trying to get my feet wet with win 8, IIS8 Express that comes bundled with win8, Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2012. I just installed all over the weekend. For the SQL Server, I mostly just accepted the defaults and "Add Current User" with an `INSTANCE1`

In my Visual Studio dev mode, my asp.net app connects to INSTANCE1 like this:

```
server=.\INSTANCE1;Database=MyDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False
```

But when I publish it out to IIS 8, it does not connect.

I've tried regiis ...I've tried `NetworkService` for the IIS Application Pool identity value... and lots of different connection string combinations, trial and error, but nothing seems to connect to the Instance1 - is there something that I'm not configuring correctly?

Any links or tips to troubleshoot this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to use the "Server Explorer" window in the VS and add a connection with the information you need. If it did connect, then copy the connection string from the properties of that connection to where ever you want. Otherwise check the "Configuration Manager" and see what network settings you've got there.

Comment: Your welcome. :) Also if it took you to Configuration Manager things, try to set a port for the TCP settings and change the server value from ".\INSTANCE1" to something like "127.0.0.1, 1433". This way you can config the firewall later on this port and restrict the network access to the database engine.

Comment: What account does your IIS app pool run under? **That account** must have a login in SQL Server, and a user in your database on SQL Server.

Comment: @Marc & Mohammad, I'd give you both a million dollars if I was rich, haha...did Mohammad's trick from the vs Server Explorer, by creating a connection successfully to the native sql server driver...the copied & pasted the read only conn string value into my asp.net app, and ran the app successfully from the ide localhost again: connected beautifully.

Comment: ...hit Enter key for a new paragraph but it saved the comment lol. So I opened the Sql Config Manager and switched to a Built-in Account on the Logon tab to "Network Service" - still no connection. @Marc, in my previous win 7 - iis7.5 - Sql 2008, I don't recall setting up a login in Sql Server...I believe I just used the basic Network Authentication, which worked okay to me

Answer (score 2):

This took me hours to figure out. But hopefully it cuts down on someone else's time. You can install all of the defaults as described above, but you have to add the NT Authority\Network Service object of the database's Security|Users (I chose the global top level)...and then go in and mess with the permissions of that new user object...give it all of the necessary rights: in short, I gave it the Server Role of SysAdmin (checkbox). Thank you to those who helped me think about the problem in different ways!